# cURL POST multiple files with different names (emulate wildcard)

Tags: windows, curl, wildcard, libcurl

this is all a little over my head, so please be specific in your responses.

I have successfully performed an HTTPS FORM POST using cURL. Here is the code, simplified:

```
curl.exe -E cert.pem -k -F file=@"C:\DIR\test.txt" "https://www.example.com/ul_file_curl.ashx"
```

Here's the problem: I need to make this code upload two files each day, and the names will change every day based on several variables, like date and time of creation.

What I want to do is just replace **test.txt** with ***.txt**, but cURL doesn't seem to support wildcards, so how can I accomplish this? Thanks very much in advance.

Edit: This is all done in a Windows environment.

Comment: You need to setup a cronjob that executes a `.bat` file and specify the filename of the txt file as an `argument` to the `.bat`.

Comment: Okay.... can you walk me through it a little? I'm on windows, so am I scheduling a task to run the .bat with the text file as an argument? And what would the .bat look like such that it could accept that file as an argument and know what to do with it?